# Turning CoinGecko API response to then plot graphs with the data | Python

Tags: python

I'm not very experienced with OOP and Python and I've been wanting to kind of professionalize my way of writing code, etc.
My question is; in what departments can I improve?

Main.py (how I interact with the other files/classes)

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import coins
import plot

end_date = datetime.today().timestamp()
start_date = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=365)).timestamp()

coin = coins.CoinClient('cardano')
resp = coin.get_between(start_date, end_date)

raw = coins.RawResponse(resp)
parse = coins.ParseClear(raw.beautify_between())

response = plot.sanitize_response(parse.parse_days(30), "prices", False)
plotarr = plot.PlotArray(response['x_axis'], response['y_axis'])
plotarr.line_graph_price("Cardano", False)
```

Coins.py

```py
from datetime import datetime

from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

import config


def raise_type_error(message):
    # Raises a type error
    raise TypeError(message)


class CoinClient:
    # Response object keys (per coin)
    # prices
    # market_caps
    # total_volumes

    def __init__(self, ticker):
        self.ticker = ticker
        self.cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
        self.response_dict = dict()

    # Gets raw data between start and end date (UNIX time format)
    def get_between(self, start_date: float, end_date: float):
        # Returns one CoinGecko response object for coin specified
        if isinstance(self.ticker, str):
            return False, self.cg.get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id(self.ticker, config.currency, start_date, end_date)

        # Returns a dict of CoinGecko response objects for coins specified
        elif isinstance(self.ticker, list):
            for c in self.ticker:
                self.response_dict[c] = self.cg.get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id(c, config.currency, start_date,
                                                                                  end_date)

            return True, self.response_dict
        # Raise TypeError is self.ticker isn't a string or list.
        else:
            raise_type_error(
                "Ticker must either be a string or list of strings.")


class RawResponse:
    # Turns CoinClient response object into readable (UNIX -> DATETIME)
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.response_dict = dict()

    def __iterate(self, ls):
        # Iterate over the array with values [unix, value]
        arr = list()
        for i in ls:
            # Return an array in the same format as the original object.
            arr.append([datetime.fromtimestamp(i[0] / 1000).date(), i[1]])
        return arr

    def beautify_between(self):
        l, data = self.data[0], self.data[1]
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            # Check if data is a list or not, if yes it iterates over the names of the coins
            if l:
                self.response_dict['multiple'] = True
                for c in data:
                    self.response_dict[c] = {}
                    for k in data[c]:
                        # Update dict_key[coin] with k(price, total_volumes, market_caps) with [[datetime, value], etc.]
                        self.response_dict[c].update(
                            {k: self.__iterate(data[c][k])})
            else:
                self.response_dict['multiple'] = False
                for k in data:
                    # Update k(price, total_volumes, market_caps) with [[datetime, value], etc.]
                    self.response_dict.update({k: self.__iterate(data[k])})
        else:
            # Raise type error, data is not a dict.
            raise_type_error("Data must either be of type dict")

        # Return response dict
        return self.response_dict


class ParseClear:
    # Reformat clear/parsed data from RawResponse
    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        self.data = data

    # Interval = amount of days to skip (7 to get weekly data, 30 to get monthly, etc.)
    def parse_days(self, interval: int):
        is_multiple = self.data['multiple']
        del self.data['multiple']
        if is_multiple:
            for c in self.data:
                for k in self.data[c]:
                    self.data[c][k] = self.data[c][k][::interval]

        else:
            for k in self.data:
                self.data[k] = self.data[k][::interval]

        return self.data
```

plot.py (not yet finished)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()


def sanitize_response(obj, key, multiple: bool):
    # Get an X and Y axis for the key (prices, total_volumes, market_caps) for coins.
    # Multiple flag is used to see if there's multiple coins given

    # Creating response dictionary and x and y list
    response = dict()
    x = list()
    y = list()

    if multiple:
        for c in obj:
            response[c] = {}
            for arr in obj[c][key]:
                x.append(arr[0])
                y.append(arr[1])
            response[c]["x_axis"] = x
            response[c]["y_axis"] = y
    else:
        for arr in obj[key]:
            x.append(arr[0])
            y.append(arr[1])
        response["x_axis"] = x
        response["y_axis"] = y
    return response


class PlotArray:
    # Plot a graph from an array/list (x and y axis are lists)

    def __init__(self, x: list, y: list):
        self.x_axis = x
        self.y_axis = y

    def line_graph_price(self, coin: str, multiple: bool):
        # Plot a line graph for the price overtime
        if multiple:
            pass
        else:
            plt.plot(self.x_axis, self.y_axis)
            plt.xlabel('Timeframe (YYYY-MM)')
            plt.ylabel(f'{coin} price')
            plt.title(f'Coin price graph')
            plt.legend([coin])
        plt.show()
```

config.py

```py
currency = "usd"
```

This is my first real attempt at programming in an object oriented manner, so even general information is much appreciated.

**Edit**

As was suggested, here is a basic overview of what the program does;

1. Gets data from CoinGecko API from selected coin(s)
2. Turns CoinGecko API object to readable format (UNIX timestamps -> Datetime)
3. Parses data from the CoinGecko API that a user want (`prices`, `total_volumes`, `market_caps`)
4. The CoinGecko API sends daily data over the time period you specified (365 records for one year). Program then gets data with an interval a user sets (30 days = 1 month) so you don't have data of every day but every `n` days.
5. Graphs the data (doesn't yet work for multiple coins and it's a pretty ugly graph, just learning stuff about visualizing data)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I can see that the code has something to do with coins and responses. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the purpose of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](https://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. The title needs an [edit] to simply [state the task](https://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've changed the post!